# Javascript split only once and ignore the rest

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am parsing some key value pairs that are separated by colons. The problem I am having is that in the value section there are colons that I want to ignore but the `split` function is picking them up anyway.

sample:

```
Name: my name
description: this string is not escaped: i hate these colons
date: a date
```

On the individual lines I tried this `line.split(/:/, 1)` but it only matched the value part of the data. Next I tried `line.split(/:/, 2)` but that gave me `['description', 'this string is not escaped']` and I need the whole string.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
a = line.split(/:/);
key = a.shift();
val = a.join(':');
```

Comment: Slight variation, for a one-liner: `line.split(/:/).slice(1).join()`

Comment: One-liner is nice, but you forgot the final `:` in join `line.split(/:/).slice(1).join(':')`

Answer (score 15):

Use the greedy operator (`?`) to only split the first instance.

`line.split(/: (.+)?/, 2);`

Comment: this did not work. The strings in the value section are getting all broken up.

Comment: `'description: this string is not escaped: i hate these colons'.split(/: (.+)?/, 2);` returns for me `["description", "this string is not escaped: i hate these colons"]` What does it return for you?

Comment: I guess I made my example to simple. These strings have a lot of tab new lines and spaces in them. That may be why it does not work.

Comment: hmm ok I'd need a more accurate example to provide you with a better solution.

Comment: sorry but i cant share the data that i am using, its proprietary.

Comment: You'll have to go with a less elegant solution then. I'm not a mind reader sorry :/

Comment: So can I just confirm a few things, first off, `?` isn't the greedy operator, it's the non greedy operator, and the code works fine with `/: (.+)/` secondly, from playing with this code, javascript returns splits then returns any capture groups as well (things within `()`)? is that right? I wasn't aware of that functionality!

Comment: Almost perfect, you don't need the non-gready (it does nothing, because there is nothing afterwards)... From the definition of split(): "If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array."

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer an alternative to regexp consider this:

```
var split = line.split(':');
var key = split[0];
var val = split.slice(1).join(":");
```

Reference: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more elegant:

```
a = line.match(/(.*?):(.*)/);
key = a[1];
val = a[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this approach will be the best for such purpose:

```
var a = line.match(/([^:\s]+)\s*:\s*(.*)/);
var key = a[1];
var val = a[2];
```

So, you can use tabulations in your config/data files of such structure and also not worry about spaces before or after your name-value delimiter `':'`.

Or you can use primitive and fast string functions `indexOf` and `substr` to reach your goal in, I think, the fastest way (by CPU and RAM)

```
for ( ... line ... ) {
    var delimPos = line.indexOf(':');
    if (delimPos <= 0) {
        continue; // Something wrong with this "line"
    }
    var key = line.substr(0, delimPos).trim();
    var val = line.substr(delimPos + 1).trim();

    // Do all you need with this  key: val
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Split string in two at first occurrence

To split a string with multiple i.e. columns `:` only at the first column occurrence
**use Positive Lookbehind `(?<=)`**

```js
const a = "Description: this: is: nice";
const b = "Name: My Name";

console.log(a.split(/(?<=^[^:]*):/)); // ["Description", " this: is: nice"]
console.log(b.split(/(?<=^[^:]*):/)); // ["Name", " My Name"]
```

it basically consumes from *Start of string* `^` everything that is *not a column* `[^:]` *zero or more times* `*`. Once the positive lookbehind is done, finally matches the column `:`.

If you additionally want to remove one or more whitespaces following the column,
use `/(?<=^[^:]*): */`

[Explanation on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gTNGsA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitOnce(str, sep) {
  const idx = str.indexOf(sep);
  return [str.slice(0, idx), str.slice(idx+1)];
}
splitOnce("description: this string is not escaped: i hate these colons", ":")
```